# Netbeans 8.1, Angular 2: Cannot find module 'angular2/core', base project created with Angular-CLI

Tags: netbeans, angular-cli

Since Netbeans is used as my primary editor, and the project is built with angular-cli, this is a cosmetic issue, the project builds and deploys fine using `ng serve -o`, this is just an annoyance as I like my Netbeans to flag errors in files that actually have errors.

**This is a Netbeans specific question**, there are many "Cannot find module 'angular2/core'" questions but each requires different IDE configuration (VS, Webstorm, etc) I have not found one that addressed this issue in Netbeans.

**To recreate the issue**:
(using angular-cli)

> ng new example-of-problem

Then opening example-of-problem in Netbeans:
[image]

As you can see from the above, a number of files have errors. All of which are resolving paths starting with '@angular' you can see it can resolve local paths fine (./app.component).

Some solutions request adding: `"moduleResuolution":"node"` to tsconfig.json however this is a standard angular-cli build and that line is of course present.

**Versions of software**:
Netbeans 8.1, Node 7.7.4, @angular/cli 1.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply upgrade to netbeans 8.2. The typescript support has been fixed and the lines which are flagged above are no longer flagged.

Netbeans should automatically install the `TypeScript Editor` plugin, and as a matter of convenience install the `netbeans-angular2-code-templates` plugin.